# Python logging output limited to ~65 lines

Tags: linux, python, logging, io

I am working on a simple python script on CentOS 7. There is an error, but I am trying to figure it out using the log.

I have a logging class that has the following logging levels:

- Error
- Warn
- Degub
- Info
- Test

Every time the log is being output to the terminal and written to the file, only approx. 65 lines are output and written (varies between 64 and 66).

Would that have something to do with the operating system or the Logging class itself? That class imports the python lib 'logging'. I will post the class if needed,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logging output is being buffered.  The default size is about 4,000 bytes, which is ~64 lines.

Output logs to stderr or the console -- these generally aren't buffered, so you can see your error messages immediately.